# How to add or remove items from adapter on data change without refreshing

Tags: android, firebase

I have an adapter with arraylist of strings. With Firebase I listen to changes on the database, and everytime the database changes, I remove or add items from the ArrayList and call `SetAdapter` again, which causes the entire list to refresh instead of just adding or removing a single item. This is the code:

in the fragment:

```
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               //more code here
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
            if (x<100)
                {
                    if (!myDataset.contains(datas.getKey().toString())){
                    myDataset.add(datas.getKey().toString());                           
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
            } else {                        
                myDataset.remove(datas.getKey().toString());
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
```

Now I suspect I need to entirely go on a different approach which includes adding a listener to the Adapter file, but I'm no sure. Would love to get directions

Answer (score 1):

So instead of setting the adapter every time you, you could create a couple of methods inside your adapter to insert, update or delete items and notify the component of each individual action instead of setting the adapter again.

Inside your adapter you could have something like this:

```
public void itemChanged(int position) {
    // do your own stuff and then notify the item changed
    notifyItemChanged(position, "somethingChanged");
}

public void everythingChanged(List<String> list) {
    mList = list;
    // Notify the whole list is different and therefore we must update everything
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addText(String text) {
    mList.add(0, text);
    // Insert an item to the list at the beginning and notify the component
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}

public void updateTextPosition(String search) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
        if (mList.get(i).equals(search)) {
            // move item and do you own stuff
            notifyItemMoved(replace_with_current_pos, replace_with_new_pos);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void removeTextAtPosition(int position) {
    mList.remove(i);
    notifyItemRemoved(i);
}
```

For more information about `notify` event go to the RecyclerView [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)

Then in your Activity, just hold a reference to your adapter and call each method like this:

`mAdapter.removeTextAtPosition(1);`

Comment: Question about Lists: If you always insert items at position 0, will it not overwrite existing item that was in the position 0?

Comment: Also, I get cannot resolve method "removeTextAtPosition" for example

Comment: If you insert items at position 0, the rest of the item will simply shift positions. I advice you to read [List documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E)). What you mean by "cannot resolve method"?

Comment: It looks like when I add the method to the MyAdapter class, it doesn't recognize it outside (in the mainactivity)